# Does $\|f_n -f\|_{L^2} \to 0$ imply $f_n \to f$ in the weak topology of $H^1 (I)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Let $f, f_n \in H^1 (I)$. We consider

- (S1) $f_n \to f$ in the weak topology of $H^1 (I)$.
- (S2) $\|f_n -f\|_{L^2} \to 0$.

> Is it true that (S1) $\implies$ (S2) or that (S2) $\implies$ (S1)?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: We do not have $(S2)\Rightarrow (S1)$ simply because we have no control over the derivatives. Let's consider $(-1,1)$ instead of $(0,1)$ (you can shift and rescale, but it would just make things look more complicated than they are). Pick $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(-1;1)\setminus \{0\}$ and consider $f_n(x)=n^{1/3}\varphi(nx)$. Then we have $$ \Vert f_n \Vert_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 = n^{-1/3} \int_{-1}^1 n \varphi(nx)^2 dx = n^{-1/3} \Vert \varphi \Vert_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 \rightarrow 0.  $$ Thus, $f=0$ which is in $H^1(-1,1)$. Now pick $g(x)=x$ which is in $H^1(-1,1)$ and test for weak convergence.

Comment: [cont] We have $$ \langle f_n, g \rangle_{H^1(-1,1)} = \langle f_n, g \rangle_{L^2(-1,1)} + \langle f_n', g' \rangle_{L^2(-1,1)}. $$ We know the first term goes to zero by Cauchy-Schwarz. On the other hand, the second term blows up $$ \langle f_n', g'\rangle_{L^2(-1,1)} =\int_{-1}^1 f_n'(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 n^{1+1/3} (\varphi')(nx)dx = n^{1/3}\int_{-1}^1  \varphi'(y) dy.$$ Thus, if we pick $\varphi$ in such a way that $\int_{-1}^1 \varphi'(x) dx \neq 0$ we will not have weak convergence.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I wonder why you pick $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(-1;1)\setminus \{0\}$ but not simply $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(-1;1)$?

Comment: The implication $(S1) \Rightarrow (S2)$ is true. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064577/weak-convergence-in-w1-2-implies-strong-convergence-in-l2

Comment: I meant to write $\varphi\in C_c^\infty((-1,1)) \setminus \{0\}$. I just need that $\varphi$ is not identically zero (to get $\Vert \varphi \Vert_{L^2(-1,1)}\neq 0$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You solved my question thoroughly. Could you write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I am a bit in a hurry, but maybe you could write it up? I also left out some details.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven It seems you have performed all the necessary computations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show first that $(S1) \Rightarrow (S2)$ using [weak convergence in W1,2 implies strong convergence in L2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064577/weak-convergence-in-w1-2-implies-strong-convergence-in-l2) or [Sobolev embedding: the injection of $H^1(I)$ into $L^2(I)$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392814/sobolev-embedding-the-injection-of-h1i-into-l2i-is-compact) we get that $H^1(I)$ compactly embeds into $L^2(I)$. Thus, the weakly convergent sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $H^1(I)$ gets mapped to a convergent sequence in $L^2(I)$ (this is a general property of compact operators, see [Compact operator maps weakly convergent sequences into strongly convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque)).

On the other hand, the converse implication is false. The underlying reason is that $L^2$ convergence is "unable to detect the behaviour of the derivatives". The easiest counterexample is to take a sequence which converges in $L^2$ to the zero function, but the $L^2$ norm of the derivatives explodes.

We start by choosing $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)$ and define $f_n(x)=n^{1/3} \varphi(nx)$. Then we compute
\begin{align*}
\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^2(I)}^2 &= \int_I n^{2/3} \vert \varphi(nx) \vert^2 dx = \int_\mathbb{R} n^{2/3} \vert \varphi(nx) \vert^2 dx \\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} n^{-1/3} \vert \varphi(y) \vert^2 dy = n^{-1/3} \Vert \varphi \Vert_{L^2(I)}^2. 
\end{align*}
Thus, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Vert f_n \Vert_{L^2(I)}=0$, i.e. $f_n$ converges to the zero function in $L^2(I)$.

Now we check that this sequence does not converge weakly. Recall that for weak convergence we need to check the convergence of $\ell(f_n)$ for all continuous linear functionals $\ell\in (H^1(I))^*$. However, our Sobolev space is a Hilbert space and hence, it is enough to check the convergence of
$$ \langle f_n, g\rangle_{H^1(I)} = \langle f_n, g \rangle_{L^2(I)}+ \langle f_n', g' \rangle_{L^2(I)} \rightarrow \langle f, g\rangle_{H^1(I)} $$
for all $g\in H^1(I)$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz we readily see that
$$\vert \langle f_n, g \rangle_{L^2(I)} \vert \leq \Vert f_n \Vert_{L^2(I)} \Vert g \Vert_{L^2(I)} \rightarrow 0.$$

For the gradient part we note that $f_n'(x)=n^{1+1/3} \varphi'(nx)$. Thus, the gradient is bad around the origin. Hence, in order to see this blow-up, we should choose a function $g$ which has nice, nonzero, derivative around the origin. This motivates the choice $g(x)=x$ which is in $H^1(I)$ and $g'(x)=1$.
\begin{align*}
 \langle f_n', g'\rangle_{L^2(I)}
&= \int_I n^{1+1/3} \varphi'(nx) dx \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}  n^{1+1/3} \varphi'(nx) dx \\
&= n^{1/3}\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \varphi'(y) dy \\
&= n^{1/3} \int_I \varphi'(y)dy.
\end{align*}
Thus, if we choose $\varphi$ in such a way that
$$ \int_I  \varphi'(y) dy \neq 0, $$
then we get that
$$ \vert \langle f_n', g'\rangle_{L^2(I)} \vert \rightarrow \infty. $$
This proves that $(f_n)_n$ does not converge weakly in $H^1(I)$.

Comment: I really appreciate the detail of your answer. I don't see the advantage of working with the interval $(-1, 1)$ instead of $(0, 1)$...

Comment: You are right... there is none. I just need that I can rescale. Let me fix this.

Comment: You don't need to fix it. Your answer is flawless.

Comment: It is a bit confusing if I claim that it simplifies the argument when it actually doesn't. This was really out of habit as I typically want to make things symmetric. Here we would only have had an issue if the interval had not contained the origin.

Comment: I have a question on compact embedding of $W^{1, p} (I)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813337/let-i-be-a-bounded-open-interval-of-mathbb-r-the-injection-w1-pi-su). If you don't mind, please have a look at it?